# load pickle files with a loop and put all the output in a function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a function named `VoteClassifier` in which I want to put all the output from the loop opening the pickle files. Currently the list comprehension in the function is training the model again, which is not efficient. Is there a way to run it with the pickle output `classifier`?
Any contribution would be appreciated.

```
models = MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier, SVC, LinearSVC

for model in models:
    ''' use after the model is pickled '''
    classifier_f = open("{0}.pickle".format(model),"rb")
    classifier = pickle.load(classifier_f)
    classifier_f.close()
    
    print(str(model) + " classifier accuracy percent: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
    
voted_classifier = VoteClassifier([SklearnClassifier(model()).train(training_set) for model in models])

print("voted classifier accuracy pct:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
```

EDIT:
The error on the last row is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 148, in <module>
    print("voted classifier accuracy pct:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 91, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 79, in classify_many
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "model.py", line 45, in classify
    v = c.classify(features)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'classify'
```

Voteclassifier class:

```
class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

    def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)

    def confidence(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)

        choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
        conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
        return conf
```

Comment: Going by the name `VoteClassifier`, it seems to be a class not a function. It seems what you wish to do is load the trained pickles file, and instantiate the `VoteClassifier` class with all the loaded models list. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to load the trained pickles file, and instantiate the `VoteClassifier` class, it can be done as follows:

```
models = [MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier, SVC, LinearSVC]

# Load Models
unpickeled_models = []
for model in models:
    ''' use after the model is pickled '''
    classifier_f = open("{0}.pickle".format(model),"rb")
    unpickeled_models.append(pickle.load(classifier_f))
    classifier_f.close()
    
    print(str(model) + " classifier accuracy percent: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)

class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

    def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)

    def confidence(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)

        choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
        conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
        return conf

    def accuracy(self, testing_set):
        for classifier in self._classifiers:
            print("classifier accuracy percent: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)

vote_classifier = VoteClassifier(unpickeled_models)
vote_classifier.accuracy(testing_set)
```

Comment: thanks I have accepted your answer. But i still have an error as the last row of my code (I have edited) does not accept a list and throw an error. Do you know how I can change that please? I tried `' ,'.join()` but it does not work...

Comment: Can you share the error trace and `VoteClassifier` init signature ?

Comment: `voted_classifier` is your custom class instance. `nltk.classify.accuracy` accepts nltk model instance as you have already done while printing `classifier accuracy percent` . You could print the individual class accuracy from `VoteClassifier` (see the updated answer)

Comment: thank you. it is still throwing an error as follow.   `File "model.py", line 152, in <module>
    voted_classifier.accuracy(testing_set)
  File "model.py", line 61, in accuracy
    print("classifier accuracy percent: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 91, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'classify_many'`